# I'm getting the message This property has stopped processing data

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

Every time I visit my site I get a modal popping up stating the the property has stopped processing data and that I need to migrate to GA4 to continue measuring. I've followed all the steps and the property is correctly streaming data.

[image: Example of the modal message]

Answer (score 1):

> The Google tag establishes the data flow from your website to Google Analytics and other destinations you might have set. Create one Google tag per domain and place it on every site that you want to measure. [See more](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/9442095?hl=en)

I have found the deprecated property via the **Manage connected site tags** in the web stream details. I simply disconnected the property there. You can also access it via Google Tag Manager via the **Google Tags** tab.

Go to your GA4 Property > Admin > Data streams > Manage connected site tags.

Note that the warning will most likely appear because of the "Page Analytics by Google" [Chrome extension](https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/page-analytics-by-google/fnbdnhhicmebfgdgglcdacdapkcihcoh).